# How to clean up an image in python, opencv and pytesseract for extracting text

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am writing some python code to read a utility meter from a video feed. I have trawled the site for the last two weeks and found some wonderful hints, but as yet have had no luck in getting any text. Rather than use the actual video feed, I took a picture of the meter with my smartphone, and the set about learning how to crop the image and apply filters before passing to pytesseract to get the text.

[image: The actual Meter picture]

[image: The cropped area]

For each of the filters I used, I also tested them with Snagit, and it didn't give me any text output either. My code just applies filters, shows the image result and then waits for a user keypress.

```
import os
import sys
import cv2 as cv 
import numpy as np
import pytesseract as tess

def get_image():
    os.chdir(r"C:\users\johnt\Dropbox\~Projects\MeterMaid\meter_maid\Images")
    file_name = "OnyxMeter7_crop.jpg"
    try:
        img = cv.imread(file_name)
    except:
        return(False,None)

    return True,img

def grayscale(img):
    # Convert the input image to grayscale
    gray_scale = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #
    # Apply thresholding to create a binary image
    _, binary = cv.threshold(gray_scale, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY + cv.THRESH_OTSU)
    #
    return binary
 
def invert(img):
    return cv.bitwise_not(img)
    
def gaussian_blur(img):
    blur = cv.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
    return blur

def median_blur(img):
    blur = cv.medianBlur(img, 5)
    return blur
    
def bilateral_filter(img):
    filter = cv.bilateralFilter(img, 9, 75, 75)
    return filter
    
def sharpen(img):
    # https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-sharpen-a-blurred-image-using-opencv
    # create a sharpening kernel
    sharpen_filter=np.array([[-1,-1,-1],
                             [-1,9,-1],
                             [-1,-1,-1]])
    # apply kernel to the image
    sharp_image=cv.filter2D(img,-1,sharpen_filter)
    return sharp_image

def clean(img):
    dbg_image(img, "Original")

    img = sharpen(img)   ; dbg_image(img, "Sharpen")
    img = grayscale(img) ; dbg_image(img, "GrayScale")
    img = denoise(img)   ; dbg_image(img, "Denoise")
    img = invert(img)    ; dbg_image(img, "Inverted")
    return img
 
def adaptive_threshold(img):
    grayscale_image = grayscale(img)
    threshold = cv.adaptiveThreshold(grayscale_image, 255, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
    return threshold

def print_text(img):
    s = tess.image_to_string(img)
    if s == "":
        print("NO TEXT")
    else:
        print(s)
        
def display_image(img, title):
    cv.imshow(title, img)
    cv.waitKey(0)
    
ret, img = get_image()
display_image(img,"Original")
print_text(img)

img = sharpen(img)
display_image(img,"Sharpened")
print_text(img)

gray = grayscale(img)
display_image(gray,"Gray Scale")
print_text(gray)

img = adaptive_threshold(img)
display_image(img, "Adaptive")
print_text(img)

cv.destroyAllWindows()
sys.exit()

# I tried the following filters with no success also ...

blur = gaussian_blur(img)
display_image(blur,"Gaussian Blur")

blur = median_blur(img)
display_image(blur,"Median Blur")

blur = bilateral_filter(img)
display_image(blur, "Bilateral Filter")
```

[image: Outputs from the code]

I did see one post where the author had isolated the text pretty well, and he said he had used gimp for the image processing, but didn't specify how. I am pretty new to python but can learn gimp if needed. I am currently unable to find any other helpful posts, so I'm hoping you folks can help.

I tried using openCV to Sharpen, Grayscale, apply adaptive threshold, median and gaussian blur in a number of combinations, the best of which are shown in the outputs picture. Following the processing, I attempted to get text using pytesseract, but didn't get any.

Comment: Not sure that Tesseract is the right tool here. Did you check [this article](https://en.kompf.de/cplus/emeocv.html#machine_learning)? It uses [k-nearest](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/d26/tutorial_py_knn_understanding.html) to train its own ocr-model.

Comment: Thank you Markus. I will look into that.